# How can I use char_traits algorithms with a custom iterator type?

Tags: c++, stl, iterator, char-traits

I'd like to be able to use functions like std::char_traits<...>::length, compare, etc., but pass a custom iterator type instead of a pointer.  Is this possible?  And if not, is there a reason why this isn't supported in the standard?

Comment: Specialize the class for your type. The standard only requires specializations for `std::char_traits<char>` and `std::char_traits<wchar_t>`.

Comment: Is it something generic or you know the underlying data type?

Comment: @0x499602D2 Even if I define a specialization for std::char_traits<MySpecialType>, the length function then takes a MySpecialType*.  However, I want to pass a MySpecialIterator, instead.  Am I missing something?  For this to work, it seems like char_traits would have to have a "pointer_type" concept that I could specify.

Comment: @Aaron You have to redefine the function with your iterator type signature.

Comment: @black I guess I would say it is something generic.  In my specific case, I want the iterator to do things like process escape sequences and present a null-terminated string interface that behaves like a normal char*-based one.

Comment: @0x499602D2 Ah, I see what you're saying now.  Sure, I could do that, but my hope was that I could just re-use what is already provided by the STL, and then by extension other classes that use those char_traits functions (like basic_string<...>) would be directly usable.  I guess I'll just have to be disappointed.

Comment: @Aaron So you wanna specialize for something generic ?

Comment: You can specialize `std::char_traits<MyType>` then you will be able to use it with `std::basic_string<MyType>`. Of course, when specializing `std::char_traits` you need to define all the members expected by the standard: `length`, `compare`, etc.

Comment: Thanks, @Oktalist, that's definitely an option to consider.

Comment: Note that `std::basic_string` is largely wedded to plain pointers (see e.g. `c_str()`, as well as a number of constructors taking pointers). I strongly doubt you can successfully trick it into accessing a character sequence via custom iterators.